# How to change the background color of a View Drawable without changing its body in recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I have a standard drawable with a body and a color.
but I'm having trouble changing the color of this drawable in the Bind process of my `recyclerView`, whenever I invoke the method
`holder.item.setBackgroundColor ();`
or `setBackground` it even changes the color as needed, but it ends up totally changing the shape of my initial drawble.

My shape Drawble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"
        />
</shape>
```

the view that implements the shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<View
    android:id="@+id/item_cores"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cores_drawable"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

class holder

```
class coresHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        cores colors;
        View item;

        public coresHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemClick(itemView);
            item= itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_cores);

        }

        private void itemClick(View itemView) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                onClickListernet.onItemClick(colors);
            });
        }

        public void vincule(cores colors) {
            this.colors =colors;
            
        }


    }
// bind
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(coresHolder holder, int position) {
        cores cores=list.get(position);
        holder.vincule(cores);
      //ps only a test change color to holder
        holder.item.setBackgroundColor(R.color.purple_700);
```

What I need:

[image]

What I got:

[image]

Comment: My intention is to change the color of my holder without changing the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below utility method in the adapter

```
public static void setDrawableColor(Context context, Drawable drawable, int color) {
    Drawable drawableWrap = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable).mutate();
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableWrap, ContextCompat.getColor(context, color));
}
```

And use it as follows in `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(coresHolder holder, int position) {
    cores cores=list.get(position);
    holder.vincule(cores);
   
    // Changing background drawable
    setDrawableColor(holder.item.getContext(), holder.item.getBackground(), R.color.purple_700);
    
}
```

Demo:

[image]